# Insufficient Number of arguments were supplied for Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, parameters

Quick help I have a Procedure that doesn't let me build in SQL Server: keep saying `An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function dbo.GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY.` from line 12 to line 15 is where find that error.

My Procedure is dbo.PAYSESTIMATED:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE       [dbo].[PAYSESTIMATED] 
(@nLicNum FLOAT,  @nYear FLOAT)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @dDueDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @nActualTaxes FLOAT;
DECLARE @nPreviousYearTaxes FLOAT;
DECLARE @nQuarterlyTaxesDue FLOAT;
DECLARE @nNetPremium FLOAT;
DECLARE @sQuarterlyDescription VARCHAR(200) = 'PREMIUM TAX QUARTERLY - SURPLUS LINES BROKERS';
DECLARE @sAnnualDescription VARCHAR(200) = 'PREMIUM TAX ANNUAL - SURPLUS LINES BROKERS';
DECLARE @dFirstQuarterDue DATETIME = dbo.GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY(convert(Datetime,Cast(@nYear as varchar(4)) +'/05/31'));
DECLARE @dSecondQuarterDue DATETIME = dbo.GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY(convert(Datetime,Cast(@nYear as varchar(4)) +'/08/31'));
DECLARE @dThirdQuarterDue DATETIME = dbo.GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY(convert(Datetime,Cast(@nYear as varchar(4)) +'/11/30'));
DECLARE @dAnnualDue DATETIME = dbo.GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY(CONVERT(DATETIME, @nYear+ISNULL(1, '') +'/03/1'));
DECLARE @nPreviousAmount FLOAT;
DECLARE @nPaysEstimated FLOAT;
DECLARE @nPaysQuarterly FLOAT;
DECLARE @dToday DATETIME;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
...
```

My Function for Dbo.GETNEXTBUSSINESSDAY:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY]
  ( @dDate Datetime, @nDaysAfter Float)
  RETURNS  datetime AS
 BEGIN
DECLARE @dNextDay       Datetime = @dDate;
If @nDaysAfter is null or @nDaysAfter < 0 or @dDate is null begin
  Return null;
End 
 If @nDaysAfter = 0 begin
   while (dbo.ISHOLIDAY(@dNextDay) = 1) or (RTrim(convert(char,@dNextDay + 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')) Begin
    SET @dNextDay = @dNextDay + 1;
  End;
 RETURN @dNextDay;
End
Else BEGIN 
SET @dNextDay = @dNextDay + 1;
declare @i int = 1
while @i <= @nDaysAfter
begin
    while (dbo.ISHOLIDAY(@dNextDay) = 1) or (RTrim(convert(char,@dNextDay + 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')) 
    Begin
      SET @dNextDay = @dNextDay + 1;
    End
      SET @dNextDay = @dNextDay + 1;
  set @i = @i+1
End
END
  RETURN @dNextDay - 1;
END
```

Thank You.

Comment: The error message is extremely clear:  the function takes two params, you're only providing one.

Comment: Can you please be more specific where did I miss a return ?

Comment: Literally every time you call the function you're only passing in one parameter.  *e.g.:* `dbo.GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY(convert(Datetime,Cast(@nYear as varchar(4)) +'/05/31'))`.  This is only passing in the first param (`@dDate`), the function is also expecting a second param (`@nDaysAfter`).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will take a look.

Comment: You should look into using a calendar table instead of looping like this. There are dozens and dozens of great examples of calendar tables. They are faster and more flexible than this looping approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY` has two parameters, `@dDate Datetime` and `@nDaysAfter Float`

When calling it, provide both parameters, for example
`dbo.GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY(convert(Datetime,Cast(@nYear as varchar(4)) +'/05/31'), 0);`

Comment: it accepted the procedure, thank you. Do you know what is wrong in the code, if I query: exec dbo.PAYSESTIMATED'7782','2008';
I get the following message:

`Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure PAYSESTIMATED, Line 13
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

I replaced: 
`DECLARE @dFirstQuarterDue DATETIME  = dbo.GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY(convert(Datetime,Cast(@nYear as varchar(4)) +'/05/31'), 0);`
for:
`DECLARE @dFirstQuarterDue DATETIME = dbo.GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY(CONVERT(DATETIME,ISNULL(@nYear, '') +'/05/31'), 0);`
but still same error. Thanks

Comment: The error is occurring inside GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY. `RTrim(convert(char,@dNextDay + 'DAY'))` is invalid.  Instead use `DatePart(weekday, @dNextDay)` which returns 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc.  When diagnosing errors inside a function copy/paste the code into SQL Server Management Studio and run the code standalone to verify proper behavior.  Thus, the code logic updates to `or DatePart(weekday, @dNextDay) IN (7,1)` where 7 is Saturday and 1 is Sunday

Comment: `@nYear+ISNULL(1, '')` is also wrong.  Change to `Cast(@nYear + 1 as varchar(4))`

Comment: Yeyyy I forgot you update a comment and replaced sunday for 1 and Saturday for 7. Now is working my Vb.net Application. You so helpful!!!!!